# Async/Await WCF client in a PCL

Tags: c#, wcf, async-await, portable-class-library

The project I'm working on is using a WCF Service on the server side (code is in the same project). I want to extend it by writing a PCL that consumes the service and would like to implement the calls with the Async/Await pattern.

As the PCL does not support Async/Await from the start I added the BCL.Async package via Nuget to the project. But whenever I try to generate the Proxy the Task based async client can not be selected i.e. generated. Adding the proxy manually via ChannelFactory also does not seem to be possible in the PCL.

My current approach is generating the proxy copying the ref class and then writing the async/await pattern on my own by using the Task wrapper provided by the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But is there an easier way? How would I manually write the wrapper using the async/await pattern directly without generating multiple async patterns that have the same effect?

Comment: Do not use TPL/`Task.Run` to "wrap" your WCF calls. You aren't doing true threadless async, which assuming you are actually working on an embedded device, is going to make a huge difference. You can however use the `Task.Factory.FromAsync(BeginXXX,EndXXX)` method...that will work correctly.

Comment: @Aron, thanks for the input. The TPL link actually goes right to the method you mentioned so I guess that would be the right path, except I can somehow write/generate a task based wcf client..

Comment: There are two ways I know. The first, is to use direct references (as opposed to WSDL) for your interfaces (which I recommend, when your client and server are developed from the same repo). The second, is to manually add the async methods using the `partial` keyword.

Comment: @Mark - did you get any proper answer ? can you share it with us? I'm also stuck with this scenario!...

Comment: @Dennis I'm still not there.. But as soon as I have a working solution I'll post an update..

Comment: @Dennis sorry for the delay, see my answer i.e. the blog post. Short answer you will have to write it manually for now. Perhaps with WP8.1 coming along in April we will see an automatically generated Async/Await Proxy..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I generated the proxy and manually wrapped the generated APM model with the TaskFactory to generate an Async/Await pattern in the client within the PCL. I wrote it down in this [blog post](http://www.mallibone.com/post/integrating-a-wcf-service-in-xamarin.forms).

Edit: Updated broken link.

Comment: your link is broken :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the /async parameter with the svcUtil.exe tool?

See more here [ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool (Svcutil.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: *Don't* use the /async parameter. It is used to generate the old-style APM methods. The version of scvutil that comes with .NET 4.5 generates Task methods by default

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I have not tested the method, I based it on the documentation above which points to .NET 4.5 documentation. Is this a new thing, since the documentation says the default is the opposite.

Comment: It's not a new thing, that's how it works. The documentation isn't clear, and doesn't even contain all the parameters. The command-line help states:  _"Generate both synchronous and begin/end asynchronous method signatures. Default: generate synchronous and task-based asynchronous method signatures."_ There's even a /syncOnly switch to prevent generation of any kind of async code